# DOMDocument read tag attributes, classes

Tags: php, domdocument

How can I read tag attributes and classes with DOMDocument, DOMNode and the rest of the family?

And, intended to be working with HTML not XML.

Maybe any useful extensions/modules to be used for this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: (reference) [Best methods to parse HTML with PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/best-methods-to-parse-html-with-php) Question specific: [DomNode::$attributes](http://www.php.net/manual/class.domnode.php#domnode.props.attributes)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually this is all in the [PHP Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php), so I give some hints:

> How can I read tag attributes and classes with DOMDocument, DOMNode and the rest of the family?

These objects have methods available to access attributes, like [`getAttribute`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/domelement.getattribute.php).

> And, intended to be working with HTML not XML.

Use [`DomDocument->loadHTML()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.loadhtml.php) to load HTML, this makes it very similar to XML handling.

> Maybe any useful extensions/modules to be used for this?

It's all in the [Dom Extension](http://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.dom.php), normally you can do pretty everything with it and no additions are necessary. [XPath](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domxpath.php) is part of the Dom Extension as well. However there are libraries like [QueryPath](http://querypath.org/) or [FluentDom](http://fluentdom.github.com/) that might encapsulate a bit more what you're looking for, e.g. for classes.

Answer (score 3):

[`DOMNode` *<sup>[docs]</sup>*](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domnode.php) has an [`attributes` property  *<sup>[docs]</sup>*](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domnode.php#domnode.props.attributes).

Note that only [`DOMElement`s *<sup>[docs]</sup>*](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domelement.php) can actually have attributes.