# How do I parse HTML using PHP DOMDocument?

Tags: php, html, parsing, domdocument

I have an HTML block here:

```
<div class="title">
    <a href="http://test.com/asus_rt-n53/p195257/">
        Asus RT-N53
    </a>
</div>
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td class="price-status">
                <div class="status">
                    <span class="available">Yes</span>
                </div>
                <div name="price" class="price">
                    <div class="uah">758<span> ua.</span></div>
                    <div class="usd">$&nbsp;62</div>
                </div>
```

How do I parse the link (`http://test.com/asus_rt-n53/p195257/`), title (`Asus RT-N53`) and price (`758`)?

Curl code here:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
$dom->loadHTML($content);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
$models = $xpath->query('//div[@class="title"]/a');
foreach ($models as $model) {
    echo $model->nodeValue;
    $prices = $xpath->query('//div[@class="uah"]');
    foreach ($prices as $price) {
        echo $price->nodeValue;
    }
}
```

Comment: What's the problem with your current code?

Comment: so I get a name and price, but I need more and a link. and such units on a page is not much, as it can be in a loop for to do?
and that now looks like
-Name
-Price
- .......
-Price
and it is necessary:
-Name
-Price
-link

Comment: You have to read the `href` attribute. Maybe this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6856668/domdocument-read-tag-attributes-classes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One ugly solution is to cast the price result to keep only numbers:

```
echo (int) $price->nodeValue;
```

Or, you can query to find the span inside the div, and remove it from the price (inside the prices foreach):

```
$span = $xpath->query('//div[@class="uah"]/span')->item(0);
$price->removeChild($span);
echo $price->nodeValue;
```

**Edit:**

To retrieve the link, simply use `getAttribute()` and get the `href` one:

```
$model->getAttribute('href')
```

Comment: with the prices of everything is OK, but how to get the link? <a href="http://test.com/asus_rt-n53/p195257/">